# Unknown host error while executing MVN install

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

I am getting below error while executing the mvn install command from command prompt.

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:jar:1.0: 
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:pom:1.0 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): 
Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org: Unknown host repo1.maven.org -> [Help 1]
```

If I try to connect toa  svn repository using `https://broadleaf.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/broadleaf`
I am getting below error

```
svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/svnroot/broadleaf/'   
Connection timed out: connect
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: check your network connectivity

Comment: I was able to successfully connect to the Link you provided. Maybe the server was down

Comment: Check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62704660/6172857

Answer (score 7):

Are you behind a company firewall? You might need to configure [proxy settings](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) so that Maven can download the necessary dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I was able fix this by binding the dns name with IP address in Unix /etc/hosts file.

like:

```
12.434.23.x  xxxx.domain.com
```

Comment: Ah this was a good reminder for me, as I was running in the Ubuntu WSL and had forgotten that it was using its own hostfile.