# Maven: Plugin or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I changed my Eclipse version and renamed the workspace. Now, my Maven projects get errors like this:

[image]

Comment: Right click the project Maven>Update Project. Then Run a Maven Clean followed by Maven Install. Would like to know the status then.

Comment: Unfortunately it's the same!!:(

Comment: Try disabling and enabling Maven. Right click on project, Maven > Disable Maven Nature. Close the project. Open it again, right click on the project, choose Configure > Convert to Maven Project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you do not have a proper connection with the Maven central repository, check to see if you can't get a connection within Eclipse.

If nothing wrong with your connection, try the following:

1. Remove all the `.lastUpdate` files under `.m2` repository.
2. In Eclipse, right click on your project and select `Maven->Update Project`.
3. Choose `Force Update of Snapshots/Releases`