# Maven:Non-resolvable parent POM and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

Tags: maven, build, maven-2, pom.xml, parent-pom

I am using maven 3 to run the application but I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.topdesk:tis-parent:pom:3.
4 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 3, column 11
at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:416)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:663)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:654)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.topdesk.test.junitcategorizer:junitcategorizer:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (D:\Masters\thesis related papers and tools\junitcategorizer\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.topdesk:tis-parent:pom:3.4 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM@ line 3, column 11 -> [Help 2]org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Failure to find com.topdesk:tis-parent:pom:3.4 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cachedin the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:187)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultodelBuilder.java:898)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:750)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:463)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:432)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:396)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:663)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:654)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find com.topdesk:tis-parent:pom:3.4 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:295)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:183)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find com.topdesk:tis-parent:pom:3.4 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:436)
    ... 26 more
```

I have the following parent pom file (part of it):

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
<groupId>com.topdesk</groupId>
<artifactId>tis-parent</artifactId>
<version>3.4</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.topdesk.test.junitcategorizer</groupId>
<artifactId>junitcategorizer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>JUnitCategorizer</name>

<modules>
<module>junitcategorizer.instrument</module>
<module>junitcategorizer.examples</module>
<module>junitcategorizer.reporter.maven</module>
<module>junitcategorizer.reporter.maven.site</module>
<module>junitcategorizer.cutdetection</module>
</modules>
<organization>
    <name>TOP Informatie Systemen bv</name>
    <url>http://www.topdesk.com/</url>
</organization>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>utf-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>utf-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <surefire.version>2.12</surefire.version>
</properties>

<prerequisites>
    <maven>3.0</maven>
</prerequisites>
```

I have the following child module pom file:

```
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
<artifactId>junitcategorizer</artifactId>
<groupId>com.topdesk.test.junitcategorizer</groupId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<relativePath>..</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>junitcategorizer.cutdetection</artifactId>
<name>Analysis of parameters for the CUT detection algorithm</name>
<description>Analysis of parameters for the CUT detection algorithm</description>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.topdesk.test.junitcategorizer</groupId>
    <artifactId>junitcategorizer.instrument</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

I tried commenting the below part in the parent pom file( i don't know if it is correct to do it), then this error is gone and the build fails with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427868/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-plugin2-12test/36429564#36429564) error.

```
<parent>
<groupId>com.topdesk</groupId>
<artifactId>tis-parent</artifactId>
<version>3.4</version>
</parent>
```

Please help me!

Thanks

Comment: What it complains about is that it can't find the `com.topdesk:tis-parent` (or at least not the correct version of it). You have in your parent pom specified `tis-parent` as the parent pom of your parent. The question is if that is what you want to do. Is in fact `tis-parent` the parent of `junitcategorizer`? If it is then you need to figure out why you can't find it. If it is not the correct parent then it should be removed or replaced with the correct one.

Comment: I removed the `tis-parent` as it from the company, so now I this error is gone but still I have [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427868/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-plugin2-12test/36429564#36429564).

Comment: That is a different error. You should look at [Stefan Iseles answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427868/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-plugin2-12test/36429564#36484350) in that question!

Comment: All possible issues summarized : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62704660/6172857

Answer (score 28):

The normal layout for a maven multi module project is:

```
parent
├── pom.xml
├── module
    ├── pom.xml
```

Check that you use this layout.

Additionally:

1. the `relativePath` looks strange. Instead of '..'

   ```
   <relativePath>..</relativePath>
   ```

   try '../' instead:

   ```
   <relativePath>../</relativePath>
   ```

   You can also remove `relativePath` if you use the standard layout. This is what I always do, and on the command line I can build as well the parent (and all modules) or only a single module.
2. The module path may be wrong. In the parent you define the module as:

   ```
   <module>junitcategorizer.cutdetection</module>
   ```

   You must specify the name of the folder of the child module, not an artifact identifier. If `junitcategorizer.cutdetection` is not the name of the folder than change it accordingly.

Hope that helps..

**EDIT** have a look at the other post, I answered there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! but now I modified the parent pom file so this error gone but the build fails with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427868/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-plugin2-12test/36429564#36429564) error..

Answer (score 14):

I'm probably a bit late to the party, but I wrote the junitcategorizer for my thesis project at TOPdesk. Earlier versions indeed used a company internal Parent POM. So your problems are caused by the Parent POM not being resolvable, since it is not available to the outside world.

You can either:

- Remove the `<parent>` block, but then have to configure the Surefire, Compiler and other plugins yourself
- **(Only applicable to this specific case!)** Change it to point to our Open Source Parent POM by setting:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.topdesk</groupId>
    <artifactId>open-source-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 7):

There was conflict in java version. Resolved after using 1.8 for maven.

Answer (score 6):

You can try with the following way,

```
 <parent>
    <groupId></groupId>
    <artifactId></artifactId>
    <version></version>
  </parent>
```

So that the parent jar will be fetching from the repository.

Answer (score 3):

So In my case, After trying all the above options, I realized it was VPN (company firewall).once connected and ran cmd: clean install spring-boot:run. Issue is resolved.
Step 1: check maven is configured correctly or not.
Step 2: check settings.xml is mapped correctly or not.
Step 3: verify if you are behind any firewall then map your repo urls accordingly.
Step 4:run clean install spring-boot:run
step 5: issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Using Maven 3.8.3 on Windows, I had no problem by explicitly specifying the relative path of the parent pom.xml (`../pom.xml`), i.e.:

```java
<parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

The only thing that left me disappointed is the misleading documentation.

Quoting the [Maven source](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Parent.html#getRelativePath--) about `relativePath`:

> The relative path of the parent `pom.xml` file within the check out. The default value is `../pom.xml`. [...]

Now, while the documentation states that `../pom.xml` should be the default, replacing `<relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>` with `<relativePath/>` had the effect of producing exactly the error reported in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Adding the following to `pom.xml` will resolve the issue:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score -1):

The  tag searches for the parent POM on your machine.
fixation steps :

1. Copy the contents of the below file to a file on your local **(Don't Copy Line 1)**.
   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.6.9/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.6.9.pom
2. Copy the path("C:/Users/bharat/.m2/repository_saml/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.4" in my case) and  add it to your pom.xml like below.

   ```
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
        <relativePath>C:/Users/bharat/.m2/repository_saml/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.4</relativePath>
   </parent>
   ```

This will do the trick no matter what.

Answer (score -2):

Deleting existing local maven repository would help to get rid of this error.

--> Delete ~/.m2/repository

Comment: how could this solve an error while on that directory we save credential for downloading an artifact?