# Get "Non-resolvable parent POM" after installing apache-maven and set JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, linux, maven, environment-variables

I'm here reaching out for help because I have very little experience to Maven and Java, and little knowledge of environment variables. I attempt to set up GlueContext locally and went through a series of steps that involves Maven and JAVA_HOME on a Linux machine.
I followed [this tutorial](https://support.wharton.upenn.edu/help/glue-debugging), which involves the following three steps:

1. `$ tar xvf apache-maven-3.6.0-bin.tar.gz -C $HOME/bin/` to extract the maven archive.
2. `$ export PATH="$HOME/bin/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin:$PATH"`
3. `$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.12.0.7-0.el7_9.x86_64`

The further setup wasn't successful so I just ditched the process and went back to my usual mvn company project. But now, it seems like something was disrupted by one of (of all of) the three steps, and now when I execute `mvn install` to my company project, it's giving me error that says

```
Non-resolvable parent POM for <company repo>
... and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM....
```

I must have messed up the environment by going through the steps, but I have no clue how to fix it. If you have any idea or insight, please kindly share. Thank you very in advance!

Comment: Have you tried closing your console and opening a new one, so that you are back to your default environment variables?

Comment: Hi @tgdavies, thank you for your response. I have closed the console and opening a new one, I also have logged out and logged in again, but the same error is still here.

Comment: It's difficult to see how those three steps could produce a permanent change to your configuration. What does `which mvn` and `mvn -v` say? (I'm assuming you didn't add the `export` lines to any bash initialisation files?)

Comment: Actually I did! But that was for spark installation. Here are the lines:

`export SPARK_HOME=/home/kchiu/spark`
`export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin`
`export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python`
`export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3`

`which mvn` gave me `/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn`, which I noticed just now that it's different than the one (3.6.0) I installed in the steps. Does this mean that there was already a maven installed?

Thank you for the response again!

Comment: Yes, 3.6.3 was already installed, and that's the maven you are running, so that should be fine. The changes to your init files shouldn't cause any problems with maven. Here's some information on the error you're seeing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36450720/mavennon-resolvable-parent-pom-and-parent-relativepath-points-at-wrong-local

Comment: First why using such an old Maven versions. The environment is not the problem. There seemed to be some issues related downloading the needed parts ... `Non-resolvable parent POM for <company repo>`... either network/firewall etc. configuration. could be cause...

Comment: Thank you both very much, I will investigate towards the network issue direction.