# Spring Boot application not starting maybe because of dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hadoop, pom.xml

Please suggest to me how to select compatible dependency in Spring Boot maybe that's where I am facing problems.

```
 Failed to execute goal on project demo: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.test.demo:demo:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: 
    Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:3.3.0: 
    Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:3.3.0: 
    Could not transfer artifact org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:pom:3.3.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org
```

**Dependencies:**

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.14</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.phoenix/phoenix -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
        <artifactId>phoenix</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-HBase-2.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
        <artifactId>phoenix-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-alpha-HBase-2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.phoenix/phoenix-queryserver-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
        <artifactId>phoenix-queryserver-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-alpha-HBase-2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-auth -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_251/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is not that you have a dependency problem, but that Maven can't import the dependency (due to no internet, proxy settings, something else).

`Could not transfer artifact org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:pom:3.3.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org`

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20611947/13211030 for the same problem (`Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org`) and a possible solution.